# What can I do if my device cannot be searched?

Tags: android

Why can't I search my matter plug？

When I connected the Google nest hub to the Google home app on my Samsung phone and went to add a new device, I expected to find the matter plug and connect it to the APP, but I couldn't find the matter plug.